# Is it correct to pass base class type to enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between:

```
TaskImpl : Task, std::enable_shared_from_this<Task>
```

and

```
TaskImpl : Task, std::enable_shared_from_this<TaskImpl>
```

Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: difference is just return type of `shared_from_this()`. I didn't check it can have impact on `std::make_shared`. Proper use is `std::enable_shared_from_this<TaskImpl>`

Comment: Without seeing Task, it appear that Task **is not a** shared_ptr object.  Whereas TaskImpl **is a** shared_ptr object.  The first one is being done incorrectly, since (without seeing Task) the Task class **is not a** shared_ptr object.  The second code example is using std::enable_shared_from_this's CRTP correctly for the inheritance part (not sure whether the implementation follows [best practices](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)).  Despite being part of C++, I consider std::enable_shared_from_this a code smell, since the object is aware of how it is owned.